# SQL query on soccer database, assume 0 if record not present

Tags: mysql, sql

Nove at SQL just trying to muddle through and learn.

I have created a database that contains scraped soccer data.  I have a table which contains each action within the game (corner, goal etc) and various details about this action (time, player involved).  I am trying to write the SQL that will work out the average number of goals that a team scores and concedes.  My SQL statement only works when there is a goal.  Some games a team wont score or wont concede a goal and then there would be no 'Goal' item in the action column.

So for instance for Team A who has played 5 games and scored 4 goals, 2 goals, 0 goals, 0 goals and 1 goals.  It would work out the average as 7/3 when it should be 7/5 because it doesn't see the games without the goals.

There is another table that contains the game_id of every game played and the teams involved, so I have tried to use this to specify every game rather than just the ones where an action actually occured.  It hasn't worked so I have decided to post.

```
def averageFor(team_id, action):
cur.execute("""SELECT count(espn.actions.action_name)/count(DISTINCT espn.game_details.game_id)
            FROM espn.game_details
            INNER JOIN espn.actions
            ON espn.game_details.game_id = espn.actions.game_id
            WHERE (home_team = (%s) OR away_team = (%s))
            AND action_name = (%s)
            AND espn.actions.team_id = (%s)""", (team_id, team_id, action, team_id))
data = cur.fetchall()
return data
```

In this SQL, team_id is the id number of the team we are studying and action is the action we are looking at.  Actions is the table that contains the actions (1 row per action) and game_details is the table that contains the info about each game.

I hope this is understandable and please forgive my probable stupidity as I am a beginner.

EDIT///

Here is the info requested

```
Actions:
action_id    - Primary key
game_id
action name  - eg 'Goal', 'Sub'
team_id      - ID of the team the action is attributed to
time         - an int representing the time of the match that it happened
player_1     - ID of player involved in action
player_2     - ID of player involved in action if there was one

game_details:
game_id
home_team    - ID of home team
away_team
```

What I need to do is get all the game_ids that a specific team has played.  Then I want to be able to calculate the average number of goals scored (including the games where they didn't score in the calculations)

Comment: Sample data,desired results.It would have been easier than all that telenovella.

Comment: This question is not possible to answer unless you post the structure of the tables involved. In your code it is unclear which columns belong to which tables.

Comment: Hi, I have made an edit with the information, thanks.

Comment: No. Still no good. Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - and ditch the essay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting number of goals scored by selected team for each game is a simple group by query:

```
SELECT game_id, COUNT(*) as goals FROM actions
    WHERE team_id = 1 AND action_name = 'goal'
    GROUP BY game_id;
```

This rowset won't have any records for games without goals, but you can left join it on game_id to the game_details table with every row for selected team either in home or away column.

Left join means you will get every row from the left table satisfying `WHERE` conditions and for each of these rows you will get number of goals if there is a match for `ON` conditions or NULL if there is not.

For example if you want to get info for team_id = 1 :

```
SELECT 
  SUM(a.goals) as goals_scored,
  COUNT(*) as games_played,
  SUM(a.goals)/COUNT(*) as avg_goals
FROM game_details g
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT game_id, COUNT(*) as goals FROM actions
    WHERE team_id = 1 AND action_name = 'goal'
    GROUP BY game_id ) a
ON g.game_id = a.game_id
WHERE g.home_team = 1 OR g.away_team = 1;
```

See [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/958ef1/2)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.  It has made me realise I need to learn before I do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT AVG(
SELECT COUNT(*) as goal_count 
    FROM Actions 
    JOIN game_details ON Actions.game_id=game_details.game_id 
    WHERE [action name] = 'goal' GROUP BY actions.team_id
)
```

Comment: Sorry, this will just get the average goals per game and will leave off any games where goals scored is zero.